# View ODF file on a website

Tags: odf, ods

Good Day,
I have created an .ods file. How can i view the whole spreadsheet on my website?
I have searched for odf-php, WebODF and a few other but i dont know how to implement it. 
I'm creating a custom website and I want users to view the .ods file when they open my website.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the steps outlined on the [WebODF getting started](http://webodf.org/start/) guide?

Comment: the "Using WebODF on your own web page" section or the "Creating webodf.js"? i have downloaded the source code.

Comment: Refer to answer here for WebODF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501951/use-webodf-editor-for-localhost