# Use WebODF editor for localhost

Tags: javascript

How to add [WebODF](http://www.webodf.org/demo/ci/webodf-0.4.2-2009-gb122af0/editor/localeditor.html) to site on localhost?

I tried to save the webpage and opened in the browser but it looses formatting and everything is messed up.

Answer (score 1):

I got this from the [link](http://www.webodf.org/demo/ci/webodf-0.4.2-2009-gb122af0/editor/localeditor.html) you gave actually:

> How to get WebODF Go to WebODF.org and see if there is already a
>   version meeting your needs 
>   
>   
>   Search for it directly in your app store
>   
>   
>   **Or download the sourcecode of WebODF and create your own application with it.**

Here's the link to the source code: https://github.com/kogmbh/WebODF/archive/master.zip

## Update

Well, you're lucky, since I use a Linux distribution that is based on Ubuntu. Here are the steps to install:

**Creating webodf.js** 

webodf.js is compiled by using the closure compiler. This compiler
compacts all JavaScript files, so that they are smaller and execute
faster. CMake is used to setup the buildsystem, so webodf.js can be
created like:

> *sudo apt-get install cmake cmake-gui 
>  sudo apt-get install git 
> git clone https://github.com/kogmbh/WebODF.git webodf 
>  mkdir build 
> cd
>   build
>  cmake ../webodf 
>  make webodf.js-target* 
>   **These commands do not need the installation of *any* program**
>   
>   You can copy the commands above (in italic), and paste them in the Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T), if everything runs successfully, you should find the folder `build` in your home directory. Open it up, you should find the folder `webodf`...  Again, open it up, there, you should find `webodf.js` file or something like that... Put it in the same directory as your HTML file and at this to your `<head>` tag:

```
<script src = "webodf.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

You can then use WebODF as described [here](http://webodf.org/start/).

## Update 2

I believe you only need the following programs : *git* and *cmake*, anyway, if you need any other, just install it,  there are many instructions online.

To load a file use this **JavaScript**:

```
var odfelement = document.getElementById("odf"); 
/*
you should have a container with the id "odf"
For exmaple a <div>
*/
odfcanvas = new odf.OdfCanvas(odfelement);
odfcanvas.load("myfile.docx"); // the filename (don't forget the extension)
```

And here is a container for our document, here we use a `div` with the name "odf"...
Using a container isn't essential, for example the `odfelement` variable in JavaScript could have just been our body like : `var odfelement = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`, but results in cleaner, bug-free code... In addition, I only assume that you could do that, so keep on the safe side and use the former way.

```
<div id="odf"></div>
```

## Note

Don't forget to add webodf's script like I said before:

```
<script src="webodf.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: That link... That editor works okay there.
I want to know how do I embed with my website locally deployed?

Comment: @UmairAyub You download the source code from the link I gave you, it is like downloading the editor's code... You can then embed it manually into your code...

Comment: Its not only downloading. I am using Ubuntu and I have to install using CMAKE but do not know how

Comment: Thanks for the effort.
One more question. Do I need to install all these things to make WebODF running?
http://webodf.org/tools/index.html#compiler

Comment: Or only CMake?

And what is the code to open the file for editing?

Comment: @UmairAyub Again see my Update 2... In addition, I'm happy to see another Arab like me (not that people abroad are *bad*!) on the site. I'm Egyptian, 12 years old.

Comment: cmake ../webodf  is asking me to install everything mentioned here http://www.webodf.org/tools/index.html#compiler

Comment: @UmairAyub Then do that! That's the only way I know of!

Comment: Do I have to install qt4 full? it is about 520 or some MBs. And I have not much space.
What if I copy/create all files from http://www.webodf.org/demo/ci/webodf-0.4.2-2009-gb122af0/editor/localeditor.html by watching the source-code by right-clicking in browser, will it work?

Comment: @UmairAyub Well, I don't know... Maybe you could try? I think if you do everything correctly it should work...

Comment: @UmairAyub Can you please upvote and accept my answer? I've put a lot of effort in this. Thanks.

Comment: I will try to set on Windows and hope it will work! I will surely accept

Comment: I wanna ask a question related to WebOdf. How to integrate webodf editor with vuejs? I tried but unsuccessful. Vue can not read some files of WebOdf as module.

Answer (score 0):

The ease of creating and deploying a simple WebODF editor has been drastically improved in the 0.5 release, and no longer requires downloading and compiling from source.

Information about the new Wodo editor component can be found at: http://webodf.org/news/2014-06-30.html

Usage instructions are included in the downloadable archive, or can be viewed online at: https://github.com/kogmbh/WebODF/blob/master/programs/editor/HOWTO-wodotexteditor.md